# phantomjs / QtWebKit issues with vertical font placement

Tags: html, css, pdf, phantomjs, qtwebkit

I'm currently using phantomjs to generate a PDF File from a webpage. I've embedded my own font base64 encoded in the stylesheet and want to set additional properties on the font. They all appear to work, except that the font is being rendered a bit too much at the top - am i missing to set a specific property here?

My css looks like the following:

```
#foo {
     padding: 50px;
}
#bar {
    font-family: MyFontName;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #00ACED;
    color: black;
    width: 300px;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: MyFontName;
     src: url("data:font/opentype;base64,<base64code>) format("opentype")
}
```

The html looks like:

```
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar">This is a test</div>
 </div>
```

As i expect it to be vertically aligned at the middle of the parent div, it looks in (e.g.) Chrome vertical aligned (middle div in the image). The bottom one is the result of phantomjs' output. The top is both layers merged into one - looks like the font is loaded, but just a bit offset.

[image: differences]

Any ideas which properties i am missing?

Comment: Every browser is slightly different. Have you applied cssreset?

Comment: Yes, i have tried with and without. I thought that it might be an issue with QtWebKit, as it does not support all css font properties (e.g. font-variant-numeric is not supported), so i guessed there might be something else?